# Testing Statistical Significance in change

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have a variable (number of children stunted) for several countries for two time periods: 2000 and 2010. I calculate the growth different between these two numbers and get the growth rate. The growth rate for some countries are quite large (30 percent), while for some it is not as large.

My question is, is there a test I can do to quantify the change as being statistically significantly?

Comment: Well, sure but if (as it appears) you are asking about a real world situation then you will need to look closely at the data.  Perhaps there are external variables that need to be considered (did country $X$ change its reporting standards?  did country $Y$ experience a famine or significant disruption?).  Real world statistics is very messy.

Comment: If we control for all other factors, how would you still conduct the test?

Comment: As I say, there isn't going to be a simple, one-size-fits-all, type of answer to this.  You need to have a stochastic model for a "neutral hypothesis", one which incorporates all those external factors you'd prefer to move past.  Again, absent knowledge of the specific details, anything anyone told you would be a hasty guess.

Comment: I would not use rates as the first option. Would first try to view this as a paired test 2000 vs 2010, looking at differences. Look at plots for 2000, 2010, and differences. Any obvious conclusion? // Formal testing: From brief description I guess differences would not be normal, so t test is probably inappropriate. Maybe Wilcoxon signed rank, maybe a permutation test. Would have to see data. How many countries? Can you show data? (Preferably as lists for 2000 and 2010, same order of countries for each. Separate values by commas. Omit any country with data for only 1 yr.)

Comment: Any such study will have difficulties with inconsistencies in reporting from country to country, maybe even year to year. If your wait for'textbook perfect' data you may never get anything done. // First step is to see if you find anything in data _as reported._  Then look at data with known/discoverable  inconsistencies and see if they play an undue role in any conclusions.